# rails routing / case insensitive urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I had never noticed that an url is treated differently if it is "capslocked"

/categories do work

/CATEGORIES won't, treated as another route

Is there a way to make it work seemlessly ? What could be the limitations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this in Rails 4.2 and it still works:  http://gehling.dk/2010/02/how-to-make-rails-routing-case-insensitive/

Comment: Although I find this solution https://github.com/carstengehling/route_downcaser cleaner which sets a default downcaser and 301 redirect through rack (see half/bottom of page)

Comment: well that's the gem he created

Comment: Indeed you should use the gem instead of the blog post Plato, because I will make sure to keep it updated with newer Rails versions as well.

Comment: Just a quick notice, that version 1.1.5 of my gem has been tested to work just fine with the recently released beta of Rails 5.0.